# php - convert string to uuid version 4 format

Tags: php, function, uuid

I want convert this string to uuid4 by PHP functions

my string: 24:1D:87:0E:01:32:09:FB:36:97:23:BD:B5:E1:18:04

convert to : 241d870e-0132-49fb-b697-23bdb5e11804

how can do it?! php have function or?!...

Answer (score 2):

You could do a combination of:

- [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) to strip out the `:` colons
- [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) the sections you need
- and concat them with `. "-" .`
- lastly apply [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower) if that's really required

Or, you could write a regex/[`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) transformation.